# genymotion permission request issue

Tags: android, permissions, genymotion

I use GenyMotion virtual machine to test my android app and I have two versions downloaded: 6.0 a and 7.1. The app works perfectly on 7.1 That means when I open it, it requests permissions and when I give the permissions, the app downloads the stuff it needs.
But on 6.0 only that permission requesting dialog pops up and although I click OK, it quits. What can be the problem?

Thanks

```
     if (!(is_connection())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to connect to the Internet to get the latest version!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActitvity.this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Android Marshmallow or above it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeActitvity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest
                    .permission
                    .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Android Marshmallow or below it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    textDownloader();
        }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[]
        grantResults) {


    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // permission was granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager
                    .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        textDownloader();

            } else {
                // permission denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
public void textDownloader() { 
    //downloads some stuff
    }
```